# Как добавить в кастомном toolbar кнопку в левой части?

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="@string/app_name_main" >
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity

```kotlin
    @SuppressLint("RtlHardcoded", "ResourceType")
    private fun toolbarMain() {
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ads)

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка слева в терминах [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar) называется Navigation Button. Вы можете выставить свою Navigation Icon и задать Click Listener следующим образом:

```kotlin
val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_navigation_icon)
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Navigaion Button Clicked!", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: кнопка появилась но не реагирует на нажатия

Comment: [обновите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1460439/edit) ваш вопрос, покажите код вашей активности или фрагмента

Comment: добавил активити точнее метод который отвечает за toolbar

Comment: я разобрался в чём проблема была